# MongoDB cross join of collections using MapReduce

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have 2 collections in mongodb

User

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "type" : "user", "user_id" : "U1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "type" : "user", "user_id" : "U2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "type" : "user", "user_id" : "U3" }
```

Item

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "type" : "item", "item_id" : "I1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "type" : "item", "item_id" : "I2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "type" : "item", "item_id" : "I3" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "type" : "item", "item_id" : "I4" }
```

I am planning to do a cross join to yield the following collection

User_Item

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "type" : "user_item", "item_id" : "I1", "user_id" : "U1", "score" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "type" : "user_item", "item_id" : "I1", "user_id" : "U2", "score" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "type" : "user_item", "item_id" : "I1", "user_id" : "U3", "score" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "type" : "user_item", "item_id" : "I2", "user_id" : "U1", "score" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "type" : "user_item", "item_id" : "I2", "user_id" : "U2", "score" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "type" : "user_item", "item_id" : "I2", "user_id" : "U3", "score" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "type" : "user_item", "item_id" : "I3", "user_id" : "U1", "score" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "type" : "user_item", "item_id" : "I3", "user_id" : "U2", "score" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "type" : "user_item", "item_id" : "I3", "user_id" : "U3", "score" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "type" : "user_item", "item_id" : "I4", "user_id" : "U1", "score" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "type" : "user_item", "item_id" : "I4", "user_id" : "U2", "score" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "type" : "user_item", "item_id" : "I4", "user_id" : "U3", "score" : 0 }
```

which I can retrieve using the following code

```
db.item.find().
forEach( function (i) {
db.user.find().
forEach( function (u) {
var row = {};
row.type = "user_item";
row.item_id = i.item_id;
row.user_id = u.user_id;
row.score = 0;
db.user_item.insert(row);
});
});
```

But the problem is this method is VERY slow on large data (U=10,000, I = 10,000). Is there a way to yield the same output using map-reduce in mongodb and will the map-reduce be significantly faster (theoretically yes)?

Note: there are no foreign keys

Comment: You can MR two collections into one but I wouldn't recommend it, instead I wold say you need to think really carefully about what your doing here, this process isn't gonna optimal through anything.

Comment: Appears you're trying to create/implement a normalised relational schema in a NoSQL DB, which won't work out. If you want a normalised data model I'd suggest you pick a relational DB, else if you want to stick with MongoDB start nesting your collections, as MongoDB isn't designed to JOIN collections.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with aggregation and $lookup

```
[{$lookup: 
{
  from: 'item',
  pipeline: [{$project: {_id:0, type:0}}],
  as: 'item'
}}, 
{$unwind: 
{
  path: "$item"
}}, 
{$project: {type: "user_item",
item_id: "$item.item_id",
user_id:1
}}, 
{$set: {
  score: 0
}}]
```